# Can not fetch outlook calendar events, javascript

Tags: outlook-calendar

Please help, I've tried to pull my outlook calendar events [outlook REST APIs js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial) but got the error.

[image: here attached image for better understanding]

my home URI and redirect URI is http://localhost/test/mail

You can check my code, GitHub https://github.com/sh6210/fetch-outlook-data

Answer (score 0):

Oh... i missed the beautiful GitHub project link https://github.com/jasonjoh/javascript-tutorial

given at [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial).